# SQL - coalesce not working as expected (or as hoped!)

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to use a coalesce, but obviously am misunderstanding something. In the code below, the code after the first from (including the paren) - up to '= en.personID) st)' gives a listing of distinct stateIDs as expected. But when I run the entire code I get an error: Incorect syntax near the keyword 'where'. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Can you use a select/subquery in a coalesce?  Thank you!

```
select c.endYear
,coalesce(s.stateID, select st.stateID
                    from (select distinct st.stateID 
                            from (select st.stateID
                                      ,st.personID
                                  from student st
                                  left join enrollment en on       st.personID = en.personID) st)
                    where s.personID =   st.personID)                                 
, s.lastname
, s.firstname . . . .
```

Comment: Add an alias to the sub-query.  `...  st.personID = en.personID) st) x where s.personID = x.personID) ...`

Comment: Thank you Siyual. I tried that, but I think because I'm only pulling back stateID from the subquery - it cannot see the personID? I'm not sure how to get around that because if I pull the personID as well, I get an error that there are too many columns. Right now, the error is: Invalid column name 'personID'.

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries need to be surrounded by parentheses.  There might be other issues as well.  This version should parse:

```
select . . .
       coalesce(s.stateID,
                (select distinct st.stateID
                 from student st left join
                      enrollment en
                      on st.personID = en.personID
                  where s.personID = st.personID
                )),
```

This might still generate a run-time error, if the subquery returns more than one row.  Then you have to choose which state.  A general way is to use an aggregation function:

```
select . . .
       coalesce(s.stateID,
                (select max(st.stateID)
                 from student st left join
                      enrollment en
                      on st.personID = en.personID
                  where s.personID = st.personID
                )),
```

Alternatively, you can pull one row, using `fetch first 1 row only`, `top`, `limit`, or something similar.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. The first sample of code does run, but it brings back null values.  The reason I'm using a coalesce is there are some records that have no values from the student s table.  This is the join I'm using to try and pull student data to match up with the enrollment data:    " left join student s on s.enrollmentID = e.enrollmentID AND s.personID = e.personID AND s.grade = e.grade"   Some of the data in the student table does not have an enrollmentID, so I was trying to go back another way (coalesce) and at least get the stateID using only the personID match.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, then you should ask another question with sample data and desired results.  There are probably alternative solutions.